# loading multiple collada objects at the same time Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, collada

i     have   to    load    the    same    collada    object    multiple    times.
Here    is     the   code

```
var ai = [];

function setupAI() {
    var c = getMapSector(cam.position);

    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load('models/monster.DAE',function colladaReady( collada ){
    var op = collada.scene;
    skin = collada.skins [ 0 ];


    for (var i = 0; i < NUMAI; i++) {


         var o = THREE.SceneUtils.cloneObject(op);

        o.scale.x = o.scale.y = o.scale.z = 0.006;
                o.updateMatrix();

    do {
        var x = getRandBetween(0, mapW-1);
        var z = getRandBetween(0, mapH-1);
    } while (map[x][z] > 0 || (x == c.x && z == c.z));
    x = Math.floor(x - mapW/2) * UNITSIZE;
    z = Math.floor(z - mapW/2) * UNITSIZE;
    o.position.set(x, UNITSIZE * 0.15, z);
    o.health = 100;
    //o.path = getAIpath(o);
    o.pathPos = 1;
    o.lastRandomX = Math.random();
    o.lastRandomZ = Math.random();
    o.lastShot = Date.now(); // Higher-fidelity timers aren't a big deal here.
    ai.push(o);
    scene.add(o);
}
    });


}
```

but   this    gives    error    in    this    line

```
var o = THREE.SceneUtils.cloneObject(op);
```

but    if   i put  loader   inside   the   loop    it   becomes    heavy    and   not    load   in    browser.

Comment: What is the error? What version of three.js are you using?

Comment: In r57 and r58 you can use "var o = op.clone ();" in the loop.

Comment: @gaitat it's r49 and error is "invalid 'instanceof' operand THREE.MarchingCubes"

Comment: r49 is ancient, and you are unlikely to get support for such an old version (or pretty much anything that is not the latest version). It's highly adviced to upgrade (and keep updating) to latest version. This pages help to fix problems in upgrading due to changes https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration

Comment: I agree with @yaku but you are loading a Collada model. Why are you getting a MarchingCubes error?